# Is the a way to turn off the UITableView delegates temporarily?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, ios

I have a UITableView with the usual table view delegates. The problem is that the table is built from core data .. so when my refresh method runs it refills the core data entities. I think this means that the data for the table is unstable, and hence it crashes on a line like this (in 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [object valueForKey:@"title"];
```

gets this error:

```
Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:
_Unwind_Resume called from function _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow in image CoreData.
```

If this is indeed the problem, how would I 'turn off' the table view delegates  temporarily so it doesn't crash due to unstable data?

Comment: I think the problem is deeper than that... more code in from how you reload the data would be helpful

Comment: Agreed, can we see your refresh method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could set the `delegate` and `datasource` propery to nil if you really want to do this.

Looking at the error, I don't think this is the problem though.